# How to join and give a default if a value is in one table but not another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL, and I'm a newbie!
Hope you guys here can help me with a SQL question.

Say I have 2 tables, and I want to a simple join.

Table 1:

```
   id | service_id | user_number
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   0  | 1001       | 10
   1  | 1002       | 20
   2  | 1004       | 40
```

Table 2:

```
   id | service_id | error_number
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   0  | 1001       | 1000
   1  | 1003       | 3000
   2  | 1004       | 4000
```

I want to do a join on `service_id` and have default value of `user_number` and `error_number` to be 0 if it does not exist.
So:

```
   id | service_id | user_number | error_number
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   0  | 1001       | 10          | 1000
   1  | 1002       | 20          | 0
   3  | 1003       | 0           | 3000
   2  | 1004       | 40          | 4000
```

I tried some queries, but they kept giving me `null` instead of 0.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show us what you tried :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you should use `union` first, then do aggregation:

```
select t.`service_id`, sum(t.`user_number`) as `user_number`, sum(t.`error_number`) as `error_number`
from (
    select `service_id`, `user_number`, 0 as `error_number` from t1
    union
    select `service_id`, 0 as `user_number`, `error_number` from t2
) t
group by `service_id`
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8e1fe/1) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, mate:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.service_id, 
    COALESCE(tb1.user_number, 0) `user_number`,
    COALESCE(tb2.error_number, 0) `error_number`
FROM
    (
        SELECT id, service_id
        FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT id, service_id
        FROM table2
    ) t1
    LEFT JOIN table1 tb1 ON tb1.service_id = t1.service_id
    LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.service_id = t1.service_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select COALESCE(t1_service,t2_service ) as service_id, COALESCE(user_number,0) as user_number , COALESCE(error_number,0) as error_number 
from (
 select t1.service_id as t1_service , t1.user_number , t2.error_number, t2.service_id as t2_service 
 from table_1  t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 t2  
 on t1.service = t2.service
union 
 select t1.service_id as t1_service , t1.user_number , t2.error_number, t2.service_id as t2_service 
 from table_1  t1  
 Right OUTER JOIN table_2 t2   
 on t1.service = t2.service
)z1
order by service_id
```